# Binomial to the power of five, equality proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find out when the equality $(x+y)^5=x^5+y^5$ for real numbers $y$ and $x$ holds.

Expanding this binomial yields $(x+y)^5=x^5+y^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4$

Factoring the right side of the above equality gives $x^5+y^5+5xy(x^3+2x^2y+2xy^2+y^3)$

If $(x+y)^5=x^5+y^5$, then $5xy(x^3+2x^2y+2xy^2+y^3)=0$ which implies that
$xy=0$ or $x^3+2x^2+2xy^2+y^3=0$

if $xy\neq0$ then $x^3+2x^2y+2xy^2+y^3=0$ and thus $(x+y)^3=xy(x+y)$

This is where I'm stuck. How can the last equality help me to figure out when the original equality holds? I know that $xy\neq0$ and I can somehow see that showing that $x+y=0$ seems to be an appropriate step at this moment, but I'm now sure.
Thanks

Comment: $x+y=0$ or $(x+y)^2=xy$ and second factor will give you a quadratic equation of $x$ (or $y$) with two imaginary solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It can be helpful with equations like  your last one there to gather terms on one side, and factor. Thus: $$(x+y)^3-xy(x+y)=0\\\implies (x+y)((x+y)^2-xy)=0\\ \implies x+y=0\,\,\,\text{ or }\,\,\, (x+y)^2-xy=0$$

What can you do with that second equation?

Comment: Clever way of thinking. Yes, now I can write the second equation as a product  of two factors and then proceed normally. Thanks!

Comment: How would we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since $$x^3+2x^2y+2xy^2+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)+2xy(x+y)=$$
$$=(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=(x+y)\left(\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2\right),$$
we see that $x^3+2x^2y+2xy^2+y^3=0$ for $x+y=0$ only.